# Encoding/Decoding problems in Li-Fi communication

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-communication

Im working on a project regarding LIFI and we wanted to test the communication by sending text message through USB port(windows OS) to light which blinks(0s n 1s) n receiver feeds it back to PC USB port(linux OS). Coding has been done in python3 language and it works for single character alphabets n multi character numerals but I receiver dont receive same numerals or alphabets for some characters. It might be related to encoding n decoding.

Transmission

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial()
ser.port="/dev/ttyUSB0"
ser.baudrate=9600
ser.open()
while 1:
    print("what to send--")
    ab=input()
    if ser.isOpen():
        a=ser.write(ab.encode())   #Can also use (b'str')- converts to bytes
        print("Sent")
        print(a)
    else:
        print("Couldnt Open")    

ser.close()
```

Receiver

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB2", 9600)
if ser.isOpen():
     print(ser.name + " is open  \n Receiving= ")
     while True:
          out= ser.read()
          print(out.decode())
else:
    print("Couldnt open")

ser.close()
```

Im reading character by character in an infinite loop. I receive some characters correctly like x,z,o.p but for 'b' i get 's', 'c' i get 'r'. For numerals 2,3,6,7 are coming correctly but 1,,4,5,8,9,0 comes as !,6,7,>,!,>.
For a line of alphabets I get **UnicodeDecodeError**: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c.

Comment: Edit: Tried using Error handlers like 'ignore','replace' but the it doesnt solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I got it working after changing to Baudrate=38400 given in the manual, but theoretically it should be working for all baudrates.

Comment: I used to manipulate lot of serial lines, but I remember that sender and receiver must agree on baud rate, parity and number of stop bits. If things are still bad, check the signals on the physical serial interface - but normally that part is all or nothing...